# Is it possible to call one of an entity's getter methods from Twig?

Tags: php, symfony, twig

I have an entity like the below:

```
class item
{
/**
 * @var integer
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
 * @ORM\Id
 * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
 */
private $id;



/**
 * @ORM\Column(type="integer",nullable=true)
 */


private $errorNum;


public function getErrorNum()
{
    return $this->errorNUm * 3;

}
```

I can access the `$errorNum` property in Twig like this after passing the entity to Twig:

```
{{ item.errorNum }}
```

However I want to access the `getErrorNum()` method from Twig.

How can I do it?

Comment: Better use uppercase first char in class name, like `class Item`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Firstly you should change your property `private errorNum` to `protected errorNum`
and then from your controller return:

```
return $this->render("AcmeDemoBundle:Product:create.html.twig", array('item' => $item));
```

Then in your twig view , you can access property:

```
{{item.errorNum}}
```

You can also access method :

```
{{item.ErrorNum}}
```

Comment: This answer contains incorrect information. There is no point in changing private errorNum to protected errorNum, that will not change twigs ability access the property. The answer by Victor should be the accepted answer.

Comment: @Omn it will indeed :-D

Comment: @Dev_NIX It will change nothing with the provided code example. The public getErrorNum() method will be called automatically if errorNum is private.

Answer (score 19):

You can directly get method in twig:

```
{{ item.getErrorNum() }}
```

but if your `errorNum` property is `private`, twig himself call the getter of it, so when you use

```
{{ item.errorNum }}
```

twig is all the same get getter `getErrorNum()`

**NOTE:** For using `item` in twig you need to pass this object to the template in your action like:

```
return $this->render("AcmeDemoBundle:Blog:posts.html.twig", array('item' => $item))
```

where `$item` is an `Item` class object